# How to annualize with different trading days in single portfolio

Tags: sharpe-ratio, annualized

Nowadays, traditional stocks have 252 trading days, and cryptocurrency have 365 trading days.
If I want to find the annualized Sharpe ratio, how do I do that? Each element multiplied by 252 / 365?
And the standard deviation
Its variance w * c w't * 252
W1 * 252 , w2 *365

Something like that?

Comment: Could you write in full sentences and explain unambiguously what you are trying to do? Also, please include all of the information in  the body of the question, not only the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the assets have different number of trading days, it would make sense to annualize the individual components instead of "combining" them and annualizing the Sharpe ratio.

For example, if one creates a covariance matrix or vector of expected returns, then computes the portfolio variance and expected return by matrix multiplying with the vector of weights, then annualizes with $252$ or $365$ in the returns case, one would get an incorrect answer.

However, if you annualize the covariance matrix and vector of expected returns first by multiplying the individual components with their correct annualization factors, and then apply the vector of weights to get the portfolio variance and expected returns, one would get a more sensible answer.

Basically, instead of doing (1.), I would propose (2.):

1. Compute CovMat/ER Vector > Obtain Port Var/ER > Annualize Port Var/ER (WRONG)
2. Compute CovMat/ER Vector > Annualize CovMat/ER Vector > Obtain Annualized Port Var/ER (Better)

And I agree with Richard Hardy, you need to work on organizing your question.

Comment: thank you. I get your point

the Volatility can experessed in:
sqrt(252) / sqrt(356) * price change ==> covraince matrix ==> W * COV * W^T

Comment: Yes, but you need to ensure the correct annualization factors are applied to the correct assets. Like *252 is applied to variance of normal assets and *365 is applied to variance of crypto assets within the covariance matrix.

Comment: however, i get a pratical question , in 252 trading days, when i create a covriance matrix in 365 days, the 252 days do not have any values. I cannot input an empty field in that matrix. Should I get value by linespace for simulating the days from 252 to 365 ? Or any other method can build the covraince matrix between differtent column for 252 and 365 in one martix

Comment: I suggest you build a covariance matrix for the "252" assets and separate one for the "365" assets. Once you have both covariance matrices, they represent the daily covariance for those assets. Then you can combine the two covariance matrices to build a "bigger" covariance matrix. For example, the NxN and MxM matrices should combine to get a (N+M)x(N+M) matrix.